# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null on JS created div

Tags: javascript, html, onload, typeerror

I am having this error:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

The code that is giving this error is this:

> ```
>         $(document).ready(function() {
>             load();
>             loadMoney();
>             for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
>                 var rawItem = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
>                 var item = JSON.parse(rawItem);
>                 if(item instanceof Array){
>                         var countdownId = setInterval(function(){
>                             var diff = Math.floor((+new Date() - item[0])/1000)
>                                 if(item[1] < diff){
>                                     document.getElementById(item[2]).innerHTML = item[3];
>                                     localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i));
>                                     clearInterval(countdownId);
>                                 }else{
>                                     document.getElementById(item[2]).innerHTML = item[3] + " Time left: " + calculateTime(item[1]-diff);
>                                 }
>                             },1000);
>                 }
>             }
> ```

This is reffering to an array in localStorage, which i have stringified, which is this:

> [1414879430956,2000,"0id","CountDown"]

The id is from here, which might be why  it is giving me the error:

```
function createBus(bus){
            var element = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            element.className = "bus";
            element.style.left = bus.x+"px";
            element.style.top = bus.y+"px";
            var title = element.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            title.innerHTML = bus.name;
            var button = element.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
            button.id = bus.id*2 + "id";
            button.innerHTML = "Ok, send off ";
            button.onclick = function(){
                startCountDown(bus.time, button.id, bus.name);
            }
            button.className = "pure-button";
            var icon = button.appendChild(document.createElement("i"));
            icon.className = "fa fa-bus"
            return element;
        }
```

I suspect that this is an error in the div not being created before the function runs, because if i run

```
document.getElementById("0id").innerHTML = ...
```

then it works.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the element with id `CountDown` exists somewhere in the HTML code? It looks like it doesn't... And if you're using jQuery for a `ready` function you can use it for an element lookup and html editing like this: `$('#'+item[2]).html(item[3]);`

Comment: @bandrzejczak—but jQuery doesn't tell you that nothing happened, it quietly swallows the error and moves on…

Comment: And what about `CountDown` element? Have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment but I wanted some space for formatting. When you do things like:

```
document.getElementById(item[2]).innerHTML = item[3];
```

you are hoping that *getElementById* returns a node because if it doesn't, the result is a certain error. A more robust pattern is:

```
var node = document.getElementById(item[2]);

if (node) {
  node.innerHTML = item[3];

} else {
  // deal with node not being present
}
```

or similar.